# Change gridview's row color ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview that shows two tables together (with merge method). I want to change the row's color of the row 0 and the row 11. I know that I can do it with the row data bound event but I don't know how to choose the rows on runtime. [image]

My code-behind.

```
public void mergetbl(DataTable DocVisTbl, DataTable cobtable)
{

    DataTable mergetable = DocVisTbl.Copy();
    mergetable.Merge(cobtable);

    DataRow row;
    row = mergetable.NewRow();
    row["Stakeholder"] = "Número de Médicos";
    mergetable.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    row = mergetable.NewRow();
    row["Stakeholder"] = "Médicos Visitados";
    mergetable.Rows.InsertAt(row, 11);


    DataTable mergetable_Clone = mergetable.Clone(); //just copy structure, no data

    for (int i = 0; i < mergetable_Clone.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (mergetable_Clone.Columns[i].DataType != typeof(string))
            mergetable_Clone.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(string);
    }

    foreach (DataRow datarow in mergetable.Rows)
    {
        mergetable_Clone.ImportRow(datarow);

    }

    for (int x = 1; x < mergetable_Clone.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        mergetable_Clone.Rows[4][x] = mergetable_Clone.Rows[4][x] + "%";
        mergetable_Clone.Rows[7][x] = mergetable_Clone.Rows[7][x] + "%";
        mergetable_Clone.Rows[10][x] = mergetable_Clone.Rows[10][x] + "%";
        mergetable_Clone.Rows[15][x] = mergetable_Clone.Rows[15][x] + "%";
        mergetable_Clone.Rows[18][x] = mergetable_Clone.Rows[18][x] + "%";
        mergetable_Clone.Rows[21][x] = mergetable_Clone.Rows[21][x] + "%";

    }
    MergeGrid.DataSource = mergetable_Clone;
    MergeGrid.DataBind();        
}

protected void MergeGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    //{
    //
    //}
}
```

My CSS code

```
 .Grid {   
    width: auto; 
    background-color: #fff;   
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0;   
    border: solid 2px #525252;   
    border-collapse:collapse;   }  

/*Gridview table data*/
.Grid td {   
    padding: 2px;  
    font-family: Calibri; 
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;   
    color: #000000;   
    text-align:right;
    padding: 2px 4px 3px 4px;}  

/*Gridview table header*/
.Grid th {   
    padding: 4px 2px;   
    color: #fff; 
    font-family:Calibri;
    background: #424242 url(Images/gridheader.png) repeat-x top;   
    border-left: solid 1px #525252;   
    font-size: 95%;   }  

/*Gridview alternate rows*/
.Grid .alt { background: #fcfcfc url(Images/grid-alt.png) repeat-x top; }
```

Comment: styling changes should be done with css

Comment: I made some changes with css, yes.. but I thought that was easier this one with c# I can show my css code because I don't know how to do it anyway @DLeh

Comment: Like any job, you should use the appropriate language. The business logic should be done in C# and the front-end styling should be done in css. Mix it up and you'll run into headaches if problems arise. I would recommend showing us your relevant css code for the table.

Comment: @MaraPimentel You can get the index of the row in RowDataBound via the RowIndex property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example in the code

```
protected void MergeGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0) //Select the row
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);

            //or you can select the color
            //e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope help you.

Comment: It worked for me! Thank you! too much easy ;) @Nacho

Comment: @MaraPimentel you're welcome! I hope I have been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can choose or have another way to accomplish this, this is just a way to do it, and maybe you could code another solution based on this:

```
    protected void MergeGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //here you should have a way to identify which rows are you goingo to change
    //I used the text in the first row
    string[] rowsToColor = new[] { "Número de Médicos", "Médicos Visitados" };
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (rowsToColor.Contains(e.Row.Cells[0].Text))
        e.Row.BackColor =  System.Drawing.Color.Blue; //it is just an example color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this after your `DataBind`.

```
MergeGrid.DataBind();
MergeGrid.Rows[0].BackColor = 
    gvwSearch.Rows[11].BackColor = 
    System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

No need for the `RowDataBound` event.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, then you stopped.

Either of these methods would work.

1. Use the row index:

   ```
   private const int ROW_00 = 0;
   private const int ROW_11 = 11;

   protected void MergeGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           var index = e.Row.RowIndex;
           if ((index == ROW_00) || (index == ROW_11))
           {
               e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the row's text (substituting the English versions I have with your Spanish equivalent):

   ```
   private const string NUMERO_DE_MEDICOS = "Numero de Medicos";
   private const string MEDICOS_VISITADOS = "Medicos Visitados";

   protected void MergeGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           var cell0 = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
           if ((cell0 == NUMERO_DE_MEDICOS) || (cell0 == MEDICOS_VISITADOS))
           {
               e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
           }
       }
   }
   ```